# Circuit Confusion with Ground

Tags: ground, grounding

I have read several explanations with respect to how grounding works but I am fundamentally confused with this diagram.

Why would I be electrocuted in the "Shocked" image
[Shocked](https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/00056.png)
Why would I not be electrocuted in the "Not Shocked" image
[Not Shocked](https://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/00057.png)

Shocked:

[image]

Not shocked:

[image]

Wouldn't there still be a path? I don't understand why **only after** the load I won't be shocked.

Comment: Ignore the load. It could be infinite (not connected) with similar results. It's just distracting you. Instead, look at the voltage potential between hand and foot.

Comment: If I am focusing on the potential between my hand and foot then why am I being electrocuted before the load and not after? I understand the concept of grounding (the current will flow to the earth via the grounding connecting rather than you). So then the load is reducing the potential difference and its "easier" for the current to conduct through the grounding connection rather than me (as I am less conductive than a copper wire)?

Comment: The load doesn't "reduce the potential difference." The source establishes a potential difference between the two wires. The load might draw more or less current depending on the kind of load. But the ground wire is always at ground and the high voltage wire is always at whatever voltage is supplied by the source. (Of course if the load is short-circuit, the source might catch fire or shut itself off rather than provide the necessary current to maintain its nominal voltage).

Comment: @Jimbo The load is irrelevant here. You could remove the load and all the results would be the same. The issue is just whether there's a viable path for current from the high voltage source to ground that goes through you.

Comment: How is this possible? If we remove the load the man is still touching a part of the circuit and therefore making a connection to ground. Why is it that on the lower part of the circuit he is not shocked **even though he is making a connection to ground!** It does not make sense that he arbitrarily touches a different part of the wire and gets shocked in one place and not the other.

Answer (score 5):

In the first diagram, your hand is touching a high voltage and your foot is touching ground. There is a large potential difference across your body. This will cause a current flow through you, which is what you don't want.

In the second diagram, your hand is touching ground and your foot is touching ground. There is very little potential difference across your body. Since there's no potential difference across your body, no current will flow through you, and you won't feel a shock.

If you touched both your hand and your foot to the high voltage wire (like birds sitting on a power line) you would also have very little potential difference across your body and not be shocked. But you'd have to find a way to get to that position without starting in the first position. Perhaps learn to fly before you try this experimentally.

Comment: So then this depends on how much energy the load uses. If there is enough voltage left after the load, can I still be shocked?

Comment: The diagram shows a solid wire between where the man is touching and ground. In the classroom, that means a perfect 0-ohm connection, so that point will always be at 0 V. In the real world, if that wire were broken, you'd get shocked touching there. Or if the wire were damaged so it had high resistance, you could be shocked.

Comment: A lower-power load connected to a constant-voltage supply won't "use less voltage", it will draw less current. So there's no question of voltage being "left over" depending on the load.

Comment: @Jimbo The load has no effect whatsoever. It's just shown to indicate where the load would be. We're assuming the source can drive the load without being significantly affected. (As is typically the case.)

Answer (score 5):

Addition to Photons answer...

Re: Image 2.

I think it prudent to add: It depends on how long those lines are.

If it is the scale shown you won't be shocked.

However, if it's 50Km back to the supply, and the current in the line is sizeable...

**It may not be such a healthy idea**.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVTsBV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When it comes to high voltage/current the drop along the return line can easily be big enough to kill you.

If **LINE_R** = \$1\Omega\$ and the current is \$100A\$ that means there is still \$100V\$ at that corner.

Moral of the story: If it says "WARNING HIGH VOLTAGES!".. believe it.

Comment: I love the addition, though I despair that the OP is able to follow it without a lot more being written to help. Ground currents can help create incredible voltage potentials and this is a hidden threat. I remember an electrician with 30 yrs experience asking my about a case in Idaho where they had to replace copper bus bars every few years. He said no one there at the time knew how copper could corrode like that, being more *noble* than nearby metals. I just asked, "Was there a smelter nearby?" He said, "Yes. Not far away! How could you guess that?"

Comment: Here's what I don't get. Assuming you got yourself on the wire and you're standing on it with your leg spread open. Why doesn't the current flow up one leg and down the other like a parallel circuit or short circuit? Your body certainly doesn't have enough resistance against several thousand volts.

Comment: @user148298 it DOES. However, the resistance through the wire is A LOT LESS than the resistance up your legs and over. As such only a tiny amount goes through you. The voltage between your feet is only the fraction of a wavelength of 60Hz (or 50Hz if you are over there...) When you do the math, even with several thousand volts AC the difference is still tiny.

Comment: I'm beginning to get it and I hope it doesn't fleet away.  Thanks.  There should be no short because your legs are not shorting across the load.  However if you straddled both lines, you'd get cooked.

Comment: @user148298 That is right :)

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1: Man touches wire linked to live wire, before the resistor.
Resistance of man is lower than the resistance of resistor(Zig Zag lines).
Electric current flows to earth through the human than the resistor.

Scenario 2: Man touches wire linked to "neutral" wire, after the resistor.
Resistance of man is higher than the wire.
Electric current flows through wire back to source.

Assumptions: The resistor have higher resistance than human body.

Rules: Electric current travels through the circuit with least resistance

Comment: Your "Rules" sentence is an incorrect but often stated maxim. Current flows through **all** possible paths to lower voltage. The amount of current in each path is inversely proportional to the resistance of that path.